# Displaying an Image in a Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class QuizForm(forms.Form):                                                                                                                                                              
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        questions = kwargs.pop('questions')
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for q in questions:
            answers = [ans.Answer for ans in q['w_answers']]
            answers += [q['question'].CorrectAnswer]

            self.fields['question_%d' % q['question'].id] = \
                forms.ChoiceField(
                    label=q['question'].QuestionText, required=True,
                    choices=[(ans, ans) for ans in answers],
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def answers(self):
        for name, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if name.startswith('question_'):
                yield (name.split('_')[1], value)
```

The result of this form is basically a list of questions with each question having a few wrong answers and one correct answer (HTML: `<ul>` inside `<ul>`).

One of my models is a `Question` model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    def _image_path(instance, filename):
        return 'images/%s' % filename

    Course = ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    QuestionText = CharField(max_length=200)
    CorrectAnswer = CharField(max_length=200)
    Image = ImageField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True,
                       upload_to=_image_path)

    class Meta:
            unique_together = (('Course', 'QuestionText'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.QuestionText
```

As you can see, I have an `ImageField` in my model, I don't know how to display it though.

How can I display both the `QuestionText` and the `Image`?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Relevant part of the template:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {% for field in form %}
            <li>
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }}<br />

                {% if field.Image %}
                    <img src="{{ field.Image }}"><br>
                {% endif %}

                {% for q in field %}
                    {{ q }}<br />
                {% endfor %}<br />
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from what i see you can just do a `upload_to='images/'` and you can access to the image like this :

```
            {% if field.Image %}
                <img src="{{ field.Image.url }}"><br>
            {% endif %}
```

Note that's it's better to name your fields with lower case (image not Image etc etc).

Here instance is a Question instance, and image is your field (which i lowed) and url is the path to your serve image.

**edit**
i've edited my answer but again please change those filednames !!! image not Image.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. I added the template to the question. Could you give it a look and apply your answer to it? Or at least tell me how to apply it? Thanks

Comment: I've edited it. You can check the url property of ImageField in django doc

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try it as soon as I can. About the field names, it's already a 6 month old and heavy project and unfortunately there's no going back now. I came from C# which uses the CapitalFormat.

Comment: ok but care, from some python library ```Image``` is a class. You should never have a problem, but it'd be still really confusing.

Comment: You're totally right and I agree with that, unfortunately I leaned that after I was already too deep in the project.

Comment: Hey. That didn't work. TBH, if you look at my form than you can see that I've never passed the image into the field. Anything else I could try?

Comment: why don't you send the object Question and the fields in the template.?
Like question and fields, and then do your for fields, but for the image you do ```question.Image.url```.

Comment: I can't because they're being accessed in the form creation.

Comment: post the view file please.

Comment: Nothing relevant there. It's heavy on business logic anyway. No matter, I found a workaround, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an actual solution so I tried to improvise.

Eventually I came up with passing the HTML itself as the label:

```
my_label = q['question'].QuestionText
try:
    my_label += '<br /><img src="' + q['question'].Image.url + '">'
except ValueError:
    pass
my_label = mark_safe(my_label)

self.fields['question_%d' % q['question'].id] = \
    forms.ChoiceField(
        label=my_label, required=True,
        choices=[(ans, ans) for ans in answers],
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

And removing the following part from the template:

```
{% if field.Image %}
    <img src="{{ field.Image }}"><br>
{% endif %}
```

Please feel free to post a legitimate solution.